# Backend frontend system

Tags: web-proxy, pre-tor-proxy

i want to have a Tor backend with onion link. But i want it with a frontend like, backend only work with frontend.

And 2. Question - I want to translate the tor traffic to the clearweb like tor2web but with my own.

It should only work with the frontend proxy from tor

How can i do it?

Comment: Hi, can you please add more information to your question? It's unclear what you're asking, what you've tried, and what problem you're running into.

Comment: I want the Torbackend and Onion page only accesble with the RProxy not with the orginal backendip .

Comment: Second : I want a Proxy that translate the tor traffic for the  clearweb - so  i have a clearweb domain too for my onion page which is basicly running under the tor traffic and backend